# Jquery on without click event

Tags: jquery, events, onclick

if we have an element that is created after the document.ready we can use

```
$('class').on('click'){
//bla
}
```

but what do we do when we want to do something with an element that is created after the document ready (like with ajax content) but we don't want to do it with a click.. we just want to do it after an other function

example:

```
$('#mydiv').html('<div id="test">blabla</div>');
$('#test').fadeIn();
```

how can i do this? any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#mydiv').html('<div id="test">blabla</div>');
$('#mydiv').find("#test").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redefining jQuery html() function, so it can use callback
[callback is function that happens after the provious one]

```
$.fn.html = function(html,cb)
{
  var tempret = htmlOriginal.apply(this, args);
  if(typeof cb == "function"){ //checks if callback is a function
    cb();
  }
  return tempret;
}

$('#mydiv').html('<div id="test">blabla</div>',function(){/*your callback function*/});
```

My solution is better than @Mark's cuz you can use it again in the document scope.